# REACT NATIVE - how to align an item in a list based on the longest Text?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

for example:

```
Hellooooo                   <Img/>

Hellooooo123123             <Img/>

Hellooooo12312312312313123  <Img/>

HelloooooHelloooooHellooooo <Img/>
```

the image should appear for at the same X axis in all list items and appear after the longest component

for example if the longest text in the list takes half of the screen, the image will be at the center for all the list items.

I know that in its can be done in CSS grid, but react-native doesn't support that.

heres a jsfiddle grid example of what i mean: https://jsfiddle.net/Leauf10x/2/

Answer (score 0):

I have provided a demo code. Please have a loo. Keep your texts in a View and Images in another View and the parent flexDirection should be row. then set the View, containing texts, flex to auto.

```
 <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <View style={{flex: 'auto'}}>
        <Text>Hello</Text>
        <Text>HelloHelloHelloHelloHello</Text>
        <Text>HelloHelloHelloHello</Text>
        <Text>HelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHello</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={{alignItems: 'center'}}>
        <Ionicons name="md-checkmark-circle" size={16} color="green" />
        <Ionicons name="md-checkmark-circle" size={16} color="green" />
        <Ionicons name="md-checkmark-circle" size={16} color="green" />
        <Ionicons name="md-checkmark-circle" size={16} color="green" />
      </View>
    </View>
```

Comment: I don't want the image to be at the end, I want it to be based on the longest component, and i want all of them to have the same x axis.  if the largest text takes half of the screen, then the image for all the list items should be at the center

Comment: I have edited my answer. Please check if this method is helpful or not

Comment: almost, all the components are in different listItems  to align text at the center of the image, but you've got the correct idea though

Comment: I want the text to be aligned with the image as well, putting the text and the image inside different views prevents me from aligning the image with the text correctly, no?

Comment: Not exactly, you can assign equal heights to them. For example, keep the texts and images wrapped inside Views and apply heights to them

Comment: in my case the text might also be long enough that it generates a newline, i cant set equal height to all components (though in this case, the image will be at the end)

Comment: Make them flex and align them vertically to the center.